# Compare SparkMlib and Scikit-learn after collecting the dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am confused about the use of SparkMlib as in most of the time, the data structure is still "local" dense/sparse vector/matrix. What is the difference between collecting an RDD and transforming it to the local vectors/matrix vector and applying SparkMLib versus collecting an RDD to numpy vectors and applying Sckit-learn? How does SparkMlib gain better performance than Sckit-learn?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much difference if your data is small enough to fit in the memory of your driver, so using `scikit-learn` or `Apache Spark`. But imagine you are working with terabytes of information, this amount of data will be so enormous that won't fit in one computer. So, how could you process it in one computer using `scikit-learn`? One option might be to use some sampling taking as many records as they fit in your computer, but that sampling might be biased, so it's not a good option having `Massive Data`. This is what `Apache Spark` solves, distributing the data among all your nodes and allowing distributed computing on it. Besides `Apache Spark` interprets python and runs it in a JVM.

Another important difference is how all algorithms are implemented in `Apache Spark`. They are optimized for distributed computing, characteristic that doesn't appear in other frameworks. Although I haven't tested the performance using small datasets it's probably that due this feature some models run slower in `Apache Spark` than in `Scikit-learn`.

By the way it's a very bad practice to collect your data, it'd better to predict or classify your data while it still being an RDD or a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks! but based on the docs here [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html], it seems if i don't use the distributed matrix, all the processing will still be in the local. Can i say if i don't use the distributed matrix, everything is the similar as sckit-learn? Will SparkMlib's operation be more efficient?

Comment: Broken link. All `RDD`s are distributed, its acronym comes from Resilient **Distributed** Dataset. However there is an important difference between `Scikit-learn` and `Apache Spark`, it is that all this code runs in a JVM.

Comment: sorry the link is here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html . I can understand all the RDD are distributed but if we want to convert the RDD to local matrix, we will have to collect it first, right?

Comment: Why do you need to get a list? If you do that with a huge DS your driver will crash due memory error.

Comment: i understand that. So if i have really large data, i can only do distributed matrix in order to run Spark Mlib?

Comment: That's correct, and that is the gist of Apache Spark, work as an abstraction to process distributed data. Nevertheless sometimes the data is small enough to allow you local-driver processing.